# How to schedule a lambda function with REST API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, scheduling, schedule

Having four API in one lambda function

1. `https://*******.amazonaws.com/dev/candidate`,
2. `https://*******.amazonaws.com/dev/incrementalfile`,
3. `https://*******.amazonaws.com/dev/increment`,
4. `https://*******.amazonaws.com/dev/s3upload`

These are my 4 APIs and I have to schedule these `4 API Gateway for every day at 10:30 AM from Monday to Friday` but I am unable to find the solution for scheduling API gateway.
here is my .yml file

```yaml
service: ****
plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  memorySize: 1024
  stage: dev
  region: ***
  timeout: 60
 
functions:
  ****:
    handler: src/server.*****Handler
    events:
      - http: 'ANY /{proxy+}'
      - cors: true
```

Need to schedule http event but not able to find the solution I also used 'node schedule' but that is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you wanna call `API Gateway endpoints everyday day at 10:30 AM`. You can use [CloudWatch Event Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) and register target a step machine that calls the API gateway

[Introducing Amazon API Gateway service integration for AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-service-integration-for-aws-step-functions/)

[Periodically Start a State Machine Execution Using CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-cloudwatch-events-target.html)